# Is there a function for retrieving last array's element value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of inputs that accepts a range of 0 and 1. `var array = [0,1,0,0,1];//that is not static`

Is there a function for retrieving the last element of the array?

```
function myfn(){
    var array = [1,0,0,0,1,0]; //that may change depending on the user inputs
    var b= 0;
    let l = array.length;
    for(b=0; b<l; b++)
        if(array [l-1]==0)
            document.getElementById('print').textContent = 'Last element is 0'; 

}//end function
```

P.S: I am editing this old and bad question in order to get give the community time to re-evaluate it.

Comment: array[array.length-1] === 0 ?

Comment: What did you tried to replace that pseudo-code ?

Comment: why am i being down voted? Did i ask anything that is not suitable for this site?

Comment: accessing `array` item at given `index` is basic knowledge

Comment: @csandreas1, the reason I downvote this question and vote to close is because you don't seems to have tried anything. You have a pseudo-code that could be from an homework. Accessing some cells in an array are basic so I guess you are new to Javascript so you need to tried by yourself first.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @Zoe well i have contacted with Stackoverflow and they told me to edit my existing posts and give the community time to re-evaluate them. So nothing to reevaluate on this fail question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
function myfn(){
    var array = [1,0,0,0,1,0]; //that may change depending on the user inputs
    var b=0;
    if(array[array.length-1] == 0)
        document.getElementById('print').textContent = 'Last element is 0';

}
```

Comment: this is not the valid answer, it will return `true` for values other than `0` as `false`, `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

You could take the length of the array and reduce it by 1 and take the element at this position for checking. You need no loop for the access.

```
if (array[array.length - 1] === 0) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't really need a function, you can even write it inline.

```
function last_element_is_0(arr){
    return !arr[arr.length -1]
}

function myfn(){
    var array = [1,0,0,0,1,0]; //that may change depending on the user input
    if(last_element_is_0(array))
        document.getElementById('print').textContent = 'Last element is 0'; 
}
```

Comment: it will return `true` for other values such as `false`, `undefined` etc

Comment: The input array contains either 0 or 1 as per specification, why do you expect false and undefined there? Down vote does not make sense.